# Is (void)strcpy(somevariable1, somevariable2) correct?

Tags: c, function, syntax

I am learning programming. I would like to know if the above usage is right or not.  is this correct?

```
(void)strcpy(somevariable1, somevariable2);
```

Is this related to type casting?

Comment: It could be to suppress an unused return value warning.

Comment: You would like to know if _what_ is the correct usage? The cast? The parameters? The semicolon?

Comment: You cannot determine whether that one line is correct. It depends on what somevariable1 and somevariable2 is, and what their content are.

Comment: The OP is asking about the purpose of this surprising cast, a clear explanation would help other people too.  IMHO it is rather silly for a compiler to complain about the return value of `strcpy()` not being used, even with the most pedantic warning setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` has the below syntax :

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

and it returns the `destination` which is a `pointer to char`. When you  explicitly cast the return value to `(void)`, you're essentially doing

```
(void)(char*)
```

you cast the return value to nothing, or you simply drop it. This can help suppress some compiler warnings especially when you're not  using the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct, but you're not really casting anything here. You're just explicitly telling your compiler that you want to drop the return value of `strcpy()` and it shouldn't warn you about not checking the return value (because it's typically a good idea to do so).

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a typecast, but an unneeded one. `void` is an incomplete type, used for modeling *nothing* (or, as a pointer to `void`, generic data).

The reason to cast the return value of a function to void is just documentation: It makes it *explicit* that you will not use the return value. Some aggressive warning settings of compilers might emit a warning about an unused return value if you leave out the cast.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is valid.

Casting an expression with `(void)` is a way of explicitly stating that the value of an expression statement (such as the result of a function call) is to be discarded.

There is an example of this in section 6.8.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *4* EXAMPLE 1 If a function call is evaluated as an expression statement for its side effects only, the discarding of its value may
>   be made explicit by converting the expression to a void expression by
>   means of a cast:
>
> ```
> int p(int);
> /* ... */
> (void)p(0);
> ```